# Is it possible to write two values ​if the condition in the ternary operator is not satisfied

Tags: javascript

I have a ternary operator

```
let { a, b } = data ? getData(data ) : {'', ''};
```

Can I write two null values ​​into variables?

Comment: What about: `let {a,b} = data ? getData(data) : {a: null, b: null};`. What is getData returning, though?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After the `:`, put an object where `a` and `b` properties are `null`:

```
let { a, b } = data ? getData(data ) : { a: null, b: null };
```

To be slightly less repetitive, you can use default values on the left-hand side of the `=`, if the default `getData`'s object values won't be `undefined`:

```
let { a = null, b = null } = data ? getData(data ) : {};
```